# error: conflicting types for (a function that returns a pointer)

Tags: c, function, file, pointers, types

I've defined a struct and a function that returns a pointer to that struct and whenever I try to invoke it I get a runtime error says ** error: conflicting types for ‘readVirus’**

```
typedef struct virus {
unsigned short SigSize;
char virusName[16];
unsigned char* sig;
}virus;

virus* readVirus(FILE* file){
virus *res;
res=(virus*)malloc(sizeof(virus));
fread(&res->SigSize,2,1,file);
fread(&res->virusName,16,1,file);
res->sig=(char*)malloc(res->SigSize);
fread(res->sig,res->SigSize,1,file);
return res; 
free(res);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
FILE *input;
input = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
virus *res;
res=(virus*)malloc(sizeof(virus));
res=readVirus(input);
printf("%s",res->virusName);
free(res);
fclose(input);
}
```

I've tried to copy the body of readVirus into main directly and deleted the function and it worked perfectly, so I don't think that its an function implementation issue.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the full error message? It should tell you what the conflicting types actually are.

Comment: Also, `res=(virus*)malloc(sizeof(virus)); res=readVirus(input);` is a memory leak.

Comment: virusDetector.c: At top level:
virusDetector.c:31:8: error: conflicting types for ‘readVirus’
 virus* readVirus(FILE* file){
        ^~~~~~~~~
virusDetector.c:26:9: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘readVirus’ was here
     res=readVirus(input);
         ^~~~~~~~~

Comment: use *struct virus* rather than *virus*, or add a *typedef*

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Did you include `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`? [I can't reproduce after adding them](https://godbolt.org/z/ENuyMv)

Answer (score 1):

having

```
typedef struct virus {
unsigned short SigSize;
char virusName[16];
unsigned char* sig;}

struct virus* readVirus(FILE* file){
```

first a ';' is missing after the '}' of the *struct* and you do not define the type *virus*, so you need to use *struct virus* every where in your code

But probably you wanted wanted :

```
typedef struct virus {
  unsigned short SigSize;
  char virusName[16];
  unsigned char* sig;
} virus;
```

to allow to just write *virus* without the *struct* after its definition

I encourage you to use an uppercase character to start the name of your types, so *Virus* rather than *virus*, that help the reading of the code making a distinction with the name of the variables for instance

---

**Problems in** ***main***

> I get a runtime error says ** error: conflicting types for ‘readVirus’**

This is a message produced when you *compile* your program, not when you *execute* it and this is because in that line :

> ```
> res->sig=(char*)malloc(res->SigSize);
> ```

*res* is a pointer to a *virus* but your cast is *(char*)*, the types are not the same.

You can fix the *cast* to use *(virus*)* but in fact you can just remove it.

Doing :

> ```
> res=malloc(sizeof(virus));
> res=readVirus(input);
> ```

the first assignment is lost, introducing a memory leak, remove the fiest assignment

Note in *main* you do not free *res* too, at the end of the program this is not a problem, except if you want to check the memory usage with a tool like *valgrind*

You use *argv[1]* without checking before the program received an argument, I encourage you do do something like that at the beginning of your program :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", *argv);
    return -1;
  }
  else {
```

I encourage you to check the result of *fopen* to check you was able to open the file and to signal when it is not the case. If you have the function *strerror* use it, for instance :

```
 if (input == NULL) {
   fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s : ", argv[1], strerror(errno));
   return -1;
 }
```

Flush your printing with a final newline, and you just want to print a string, so in *main* replace

> ```
> printf("%s",res->virusName);
> ```

by

```
puts(res->virusName);
```

---

**Problems in** ***readVirus***

In

> ```
> fread(&res->SigSize,2,1,file);
> fread(&res->virusName,16,1,file);
> ```

do not use literal number for the size, use *sizeof* to get the right size whatever happens :

> ```
> fread(&res->SigSize, sizeof(res->SigSize), 1, file);
> fread(&res->virusName, sizeof(res->virusNamee), 1, file);
> ```

I also recommend you to check your reads success and to signal when there is an error

Are you sure the file is a binary file where *sigSize* is the binary representation ? I mean for the size 1234 the file contains the byte of code 4 then the byte of code 210 or the reverse

Comment: thanks for answering.
actually I did define, I just forgot to type it here :)
I'm going to edit it.
anyways I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @AmroAnabtawi yes, notice you see that easily not puting all in a block as you did, having indent and only "} virus;" on the last line is much more readable

Comment: @AmroAnabtawi I edited my answer to add more remarks